# Append inside a child difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my current situation. I got one parent called "box" which got 15 childrens inside called item.
Then I got a loop where I append some text that should be inside the children div. If I append it directly inside the children the code gets messed up and I get the 15 things I want to inside in each children in all of them. So I have to append inside my parent. However I found this smart function called appendChild which at first was not a function because I wanted to insert a string if I understood correctly... Then I found this solution In how to make it a function but in the end it still doesn't gets placed in my children div. How am I supposed to do in my case? I guess

This is my code at the moment;

```
<div id = "box">
  <div class = "item"></div> X15
</div>
```

```
$.each() {
    var element = document.getElementById("result");
    element.appendChild("coolText");
});
```

Got this error last check: `Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`

Comment: It's unclear that is the desired result and what's the actual HTML you have... Please create a [mcve]

Comment: `$.each() {` is not the correct syntax for an each loop - please include your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a forEach to iterate the items and append the content one by one. Like this:

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach(item => {
  let content = document.createTextNode("text");
  item.append(content);
});
```

```html
<div id = "box">
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to use Jquey

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

$.each(items, (i, item) => {
  let content = document.createTextNode("text");
  item.append(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "box">
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I think like you, that [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), OP seems to want to use jquery

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I updated the response with the JQuery version

Comment: Thank you was my desired output!

Answer (score 0):

For use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) you need to pass `items` like:

```js
const items = $('.item');

$.each(items, (i, item) => {
  $(item).text('text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "box">
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
  <div class = "item"></div>
</div>
```